# touchpad freezes after sleep mode debian

Tags: debian, kde, touchpad

I have KDE installed with debian, and every time the PC is put to sleep mode, the touchpad (USB mouse works fine though) becomes non-responsive. I tried most of the solutions online which mostly suggest trying:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

But this doesn't work at all for me. Where is this problem coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this issue is resolved.
I noticed this doesn't happen because PC is suspended but only when I close the laptop lid. Apparently it's a KDE-specific issue. when I toggle the touchpad on after PC resumes, the touchpad works fine.